# How to batch rename files (.jpg) randomly?

Tags: batch-rename

Ok, so I have a digital photo frame that I have, and view my photos from a USB.
Everything works fine, however, there is no way to display the pictures randomly. So, I have to watch my pictures in order, which is fine but not really what I want.

I am wondering if there is a way to have my .jpg pictures, that I view to be batch renamed, but renamed randomly? Be it adding random characters to the start of the name or replacing the characters before .jpg

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose the following could work. Assuming the prefix of your filenames is "DSC" you can use the following command in the terminal (*untested!*)

```
cd /path/to/photos
rename 's/DSC/'$RANDOM'/' *.jpg
```

This uses the perl rename command to match regular expressions and replace them. In this case, we are substituting "DSC" with a random number in the filename for all .jpg files. Change the "DSC" to whatever your photos' prefix is.

another method (also untested) is with a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.jpg; do
  mv "$f" $RANDOM-"$f"
done
```

Comment: Great thanks I will try this tonight after work.

Comment: I renamed all the files from file-2.jpg to file.jpg, really helpful,

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash    
for img in *.jpg; do
newname=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc a-z0-9 | head -c 8)
mv "$img" "$newname".jpg
done
```

This will shuffle all `jpg` files to random names.

Comment: Done. This will shuffle all jpg files to random names. The echo was what I've used to validate the script, it is now removed.

Answer (score 1):

Following one line script works for file names with white chars.

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv -n "$f" "${f/*/$RANDOM.jpg}"; done
```

Comment: This is possibly dangerous and may cause loss of pictures.

Comment: Indeed, previous version of script could overwrite existing file.

Comment: The risk of collision is high. `$RANDOM` is between 0 and 32767. I would not recommend using this function. Or at least replace `$RANDOM` by `$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc a-z0-9 | head -c 8 )`